# Time interval distribution between events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am standing in front of a restaurant. Every time a customer goes in the restaurant, I want to make a prediction of `dt` (`dt` is the time interval between the next customer and the current customer). What distribution should I use to predict `dt`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few distributions you can use. You can use an exponential distribution $X\sim \textrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$

$$ f(x;\lambda) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} &  x \geq  0 \\ \\ 0   &  x <0    \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{1}$$

which describes the time between events in a Poisson process. You can also use a Gamma distribution. $X \sim \textrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta) $ with mass function

$$ f(x;\alpha, \beta ) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} }{\Gamma(\alpha)}  \tag{2} $$
where $ x >  0 , \alpha ,\beta >0$

This is an example problem I found.

> Example Students arrive at a local bar and restaurant according to an
>   approximate Poisson process at a mean rate of 30 students per hour.
>   What is the probability that the bouncer has to wait more than 3
>   minutes to card the next student?

Ok, I'm pulling this from [here.](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/140/) . It notes if $X$ is the number of students then the poisson mean $\lambda$  we have $30$ per hour or $\frac{1}{2}$ . Denoting $W$  the waiting time between students we would expect the $\theta =\frac{1}{\lambda} = 2$ minutes between every arrival. Since $W$ is exponentially distributed we use the pdf above $ W \sim \textrm{Exponetial}(\frac{1}{2})$

$$ f(w;\frac{1}{2}) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} w} &  w \geq  0 \\ \\ 0   &  w <0    \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{3}$$

Comment: Is $x$ here corresponding to my $dt$ ? And is $\lambda$ the expected event counts within a given time? Could you please elaborate how do I choose $\lambda$ in this example? Thanks!

Comment: the mean is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ it is describing the lengths of time between a poisson process. $x$ is describing how the probability of how long you would have to wait.

Comment: So if the expected customer number is 24 per day (1440 mins), is the average time length between customer 60 min? So $mean$ = 60? and $1/\lambda$  = 0.01667?

Comment: one second let me write something, it is an example problem.

Comment: If the poisson mean $\lambda $ for the day is 24  we divide can divide for the poisson rate for the how $ \frac{\lambda}{24}$ then do $\frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}$ So there should be one person arriving every hour and you're right on the last part.